# What would describe the following basic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found the following sequence in a programming tutorial and thought it look neat and noticed the pattern, but am mathematically challenged and can not quite describe it algebraically. Here is what it boils down to...

1 + 20 + 300 + 4000 + 50000 = 54321

---

I can see how the numbers add together to result in a countdown of sorts, but how would you describ going from `1` to `20` to `300` and so forth? What sort of formula might cover this.

Comment: Typo, I think -- I guess you mean 4000 (not 400) and 50000 (not 5000)?

Comment: Yes, thank you @MPW. qaphla, if you want to make that an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula for the $n$th term is $t_n = n * 10^{n - 1}$ (Assuming that your first term is indexed with $n = 1$.)

For a recursive definition:

$$t_n = \left\{\begin{align*}
1 & &\text{If } n = 1\\\\
\frac{10n}{n - 1}t_{n - 1} & &\text{Otherwise}
\end{align*}\right.$$

Comment: Seems to be a typo in your formula. $10n \to 10t_{n-1}$